# Create combine dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have two dataframes (DF1 and DF2), and I want to create a combined dataframe referred to as DF_MAIN. For clarity, DF1 consists of 5 columns, while DF2 has 3 columns. My goal is to construct DF_MAIN with a total of 10 columns, organized as follows: the first 5 columns from DF1, followed by 2 empty columns, and then the remaining 3 columns from DF2. It's worth noting that the number of rows and columns in these input dataframes may vary, but my objective is to merge them into a single comprehensive dataframe with the specified column structure.

Sample Dataframe-

```
# Create a sample dataframe 
DF1 <- data.frame(
  A = sample(c("text", "string", NA, "", "123", 1.23, "#N/A"), 10, replace = TRUE),
  B = sample(c("text", "string", NA, "", "123", 1.23, "#N/A"), 10, replace = TRUE),
  C = sample(c("text", "string", NA, "", "123", 1.23, "#N/A"), 10, replace = TRUE)
)


set.seed(456)

DF2 <- data.frame(
  D = sample(c("text", "string", NA, "", "456", 4.56, "#N/A"), 20, replace = TRUE),
  E = sample(c("text", "string", NA, "", "789", 7.89, "#N/A"), 20, replace = TRUE),
  F = sample(c("text", "string", NA, "", "123", 1.23, "#N/A"), 20, replace = TRUE),
  G = sample(c("text", "string", NA, "", "987", 9.87, "#N/A"), 20, replace = TRUE),
  H = sample(c("text", "string", NA, "", "321", 3.21, "#N/A"), 20, replace = TRUE)
)

print(DF1)
print(DF2)
```

Comment: This problem needs a minimal reproducible example.  If the data frames have different row numbers, do they have a common feature they can be matched with?  Is it purely row number?  https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/16730940

Comment: Why do you want empty columns?  Is that purely for aesthetics?  There is rarely a reason to create empty columns unless you are planning to fill them with something...

Comment: @PaulStaffordAllen- Yes, I'm planning to fill them but that part is manual.

Comment: `cbind(DF1, empty1 = NA, empty2 = NA, DF2)`

Comment: @GregorThomas - It is not working as I have different number of rows in my data frame.

Comment: I would suggest modifying your example to reflect that.

Comment: And, in that case, what do you want the result to look like? Truncate to the shortest row count? Keep the longer row count but fill in `NA`? Something else?

Comment: "DF1 consists of 5 columns ..." nope, other way round. For a potential solution it might be important which way it appears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If DF1 is smaller than DF2, using `rbind` and `cbind` with `matrix` to stitch together non-matching rows and columns respectively.

```
data.frame(
  cbind(matrix(NA, nrow=nrow(DF1), ncol=ncol(DF2) - ncol(DF1)), DF1) |> 
    (\(x){
      nms <- names(x)
      rbind(as.matrix(x), 
        setNames(
          matrix(NA, nrow=nrow(DF2) - nrow(DF1), ncol=ncol(DF2)), 
          nms))
    })(), 
  DF2)
     X1   X2      A    B    C      D      E      F      G      H
1  <NA> <NA> string <NA>  123    456    789   <NA>   9.87   text
2  <NA> <NA>        1.23 #N/A    456                 text   3.21
3  <NA> <NA>   text      text   <NA>   7.89   1.23   <NA> string
4  <NA> <NA>                    4.56   #N/A   <NA>   #N/A   <NA>
5  <NA> <NA>   text <NA> #N/A    456   text string string    321
6  <NA> <NA>    123 1.23 text          text   1.23   <NA>   3.21
7  <NA> <NA>    123 <NA>  123   <NA>   7.89   <NA>   #N/A   <NA>
8  <NA> <NA>   text <NA> text   text    789   1.23   text   text
9  <NA> <NA>    123             4.56   text   <NA>              
10 <NA> <NA>    123 text  123   #N/A string   #N/A   #N/A   <NA>
11 <NA> <NA>   <NA> <NA> <NA> string          text          3.21
12 <NA> <NA>   <NA> <NA> <NA>   text string          text    321
13 <NA> <NA>   <NA> <NA> <NA>   #N/A   <NA>        string string
14 <NA> <NA>   <NA> <NA> <NA> string          text   text string
15 <NA> <NA>   <NA> <NA> <NA>   <NA>          text    987   <NA>
16 <NA> <NA>   <NA> <NA> <NA>   <NA> string   1.23   9.87    321
17 <NA> <NA>   <NA> <NA> <NA>   #N/A   #N/A string        string
18 <NA> <NA>   <NA> <NA> <NA>   4.56   text   #N/A   <NA>   <NA>
19 <NA> <NA>   <NA> <NA> <NA>   4.56 string   <NA>   #N/A       
20 <NA> <NA>   <NA> <NA> <NA>    456   text   1.23   text   <NA>
```

Answer (score 1):

If we modify the sample data to have different row counts (and to make it more minimal), we can use `full_join` to pad the shorter data frame with `NA`s:

```
set.seed(456)

DF1 <- data.frame(
  A = sample(c("text", "string", NA, "", "123", 1.23, "#N/A"), 2, replace = TRUE),
  B = sample(c("text", "string", NA, "", "123", 1.23, "#N/A"), 2, replace = TRUE),
  C = sample(c("text", "string", NA, "", "123", 1.23, "#N/A"), 2, replace = TRUE)
)

DF2 <- data.frame(
  D = sample(c("text", "string", NA, "", "456", 4.56, "#N/A"), 3, replace = TRUE),
  E = sample(c("text", "string", NA, "", "789", 7.89, "#N/A"), 3, replace = TRUE),
  F = sample(c("text", "string", NA, "", "123", 1.23, "#N/A"), 3, replace = TRUE),
  G = sample(c("text", "string", NA, "", "987", 9.87, "#N/A"), 3, replace = TRUE),
  H = sample(c("text", "string", NA, "", "321", 3.21, "#N/A"), 3, replace = TRUE)
)

empty = data.frame(empty1 = NA, empty2 = NA)


library(dplyr)
DF1 |> 
  mutate(id = row_number()) |>
  full_join(mutate(empty, id = row_number()), by = "id") |>
  full_join(mutate(DF2, id = row_number()), by = "id") |>
  select(-id)
#      A    B    C empty1 empty2    D      E      F    G    H
# 1  123 <NA>  123     NA     NA <NA>   #N/A   #N/A <NA> 3.21
# 2  123 1.23          NA     NA text string string #N/A  321
# 3 <NA> <NA> <NA>     NA     NA 4.56   text   <NA> 9.87  321
```

We could change the last `full_join` to an `inner_join` to instead truncate to the smaller row count.